# Retrieving Array from parse server and displaying the data in a list view

Tags: android, parse-platform, parse-android-sdk

I'm new to android and I need help in retrieving the array that I created in parse server named as "busStops" but I can't figure out where the problem exists in my code

```
 ParseQuery<ParseObject> parseQuery = new ParseQuery<ParseObject> 
("RouteDetails");

 parseQuery.whereEqualTo("routeNumber",searchView.getText().toString());

    parseQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> busStops, ParseException e) {
            if(e == null){
                final List<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (ParseObject parseObject : busStops){
                        if (parseObject.getList("busStops") != null) {
                                arrayList.add(parseObject.getList("busStops").toString());
                        }
                    }
                arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(SearchForRoutes.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arrayList);
                listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: 'routeNumber' is a number type or string type in parse-server? If a number then try converting searchView.getText() to a number before passing to parse query.

Comment: I have tried searchView.getText() it still does not works

Comment: What is the data type of 'routeNumber' in parse-server?

Comment: routeNumber is of type int in parse server

Comment: Try using Integer.parseInt(searchView.getText())

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to show an Array in a ListView. You should use getJSONArray instead of getList in your JAVA code. See my code below.

My structure class is:

[image]

Then, I added the code below into my Activity (MainActivity.java):

```
final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listviewA);

    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("RouteDetails");
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        public void done(List<ParseObject> results, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                for(int i = 0; i < results.size(); i++) {
                    JSONArray array = results.get(i).getJSONArray("busStop");

                    for(int j = 0; j < array.length(); j++) {
                        try {
                            dataList.add(array.getString(j));
                        } catch (JSONException e1) {
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                    myArray = dataList.toArray(new String[dataList.size()]);

                    ArrayAdapter<String> adapterList
                            = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice, myArray);

                    listView.setAdapter(adapterList);

                }
            } else {
                final Toast toast = Toast.makeText(
                        MainActivity.this,
                        String.valueOf("Error =>" + e.getMessage()),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                );
                toast.show();
            }
        }
    });
```

And the result will be something like as this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you may don't need to create another *ArrayList* than the list that is returned by *parseObject.getList("busStops")*. You can directly pass it to the adapter constructor. But since you may want to do a process on the list, iterate the list like :
`for(Object s : parseObject.getList("busStops") { String current = s.toString(); }`

Also you can save the list to another ArrayList by passing it to ArrayList constructor.
`ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<>(parseObject.getList("busStops"))`

And finally, you can fix your code (that is worst-practice :) ) by simply deleting the *.toString()* from the line in your none-null if statement and changing add to addAll.
like this : `arrayList.addAll(parseObject.getList("busStops"));`